# How to get the author of a post? (Node.js, MongoDb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to include the user's username, who created the post, in each post. How do I do that? (My `User` and `Article` are two different collections in the same database). I have tried adding
`"author: req.user._id"` inside the `create` method but I got an error `"Cannot read property '_id' of undefined"`.

Here is my article.model

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
    var schema = mongoose.Schema(
      {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        published: Boolean,
        author: {
          id: {
              type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: "user"
          },
          username: String
      },
        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
    schema.method("toJSON", function() {
      const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
      object.id = _id;
      return object;
    });
  
    const Article = mongoose.model("article", schema);
    return Article;
  };
```

User.model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

Create article method inside article.controller

```
const db = require("../model/app");
const { options } = require("../routes/user");
const User = require("../model/User");
const Article = db.articles;
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");


// Create and Save a new Tutorial
exports.create = (req, res) => {
   // Validate request
   if (!req.body.title || !req.body.description) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Content can not be empty!" });
    return;
  }
  // Create a Tutorial
  const article = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    published: req.body.published ? req.body.published : true,
    created: req.body.created,
    author: {
      id: req.user._id,
      username: req.user.username
  }
  });

  // Save Tutorial in the database
  article
    .save(article)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the article."
      });
    });
};

// Retrieve all articles from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    const title = req.query.title;
    var condition = title ? { title: { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i" } } : {};
    Article.find(condition).sort({createdAt: 'descending'})
      .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving articles."
        });
      });
};

// Find a single Tutorial with an id
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    Article.findById(id)
      .then(data => {
        if (!data)
          res.status(404).send({ message: "Not found article with id " + id });
        else res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res
          .status(500)
          .send({ message: "Error retrieving article with id=" + id });
      });
};

// Update a Tutorial by the id in the request
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          message: "Data to update can not be empty!"
        });
      }
    
      const id = req.params.id;
    
      Article.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { useFindAndModify: false })
        .then(data => {
          if (!data) {
            res.status(404).send({
              message: `Cannot update Article with id=${id}. Maybe Article was not found!`
            });
          } else res.send({ message: "Article was updated successfully." });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: "Error updating Article with id=" + id
          });
        });
};

// Delete a Tutorial with the specified id in the request
exports.delete = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    Article.findByIdAndRemove(id)
      .then(data => {
        if (!data) {
          res.status(404).send({
            message: `Cannot delete Article with id=${id}. Maybe Article was not found!`
          });
        } else {
          res.send({
            message: "Article was deleted successfully!"
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Could not delete Article with id=" + id
        });
      });
};

// Delete all Tutorials from the database.
exports.deleteAll = (req, res) => {
    Article.deleteMany({})
    .then(data => {
      res.send({
        message: `${data.deletedCount} Articles were deleted successfully!`
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while removing all articles."
      });
    });
};

// Find all published Tutorials
exports.findAllPublished = (req, res) => {
    Article.find({ published: true })
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving articles."
      });
    });
};
```

auth middleware

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var Article = require('../model/article.model');

module.exports = { checkUser: function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("authorization");
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth Error" });

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "randomString");
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Invalid Token" });
  }
}
}
```

article.route

```
module.exports = app => {
    const articles = require("../controllers/article.controller.js");
    const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
    var router = require("express").Router();
    var {checkUser} = auth;

  
    // Create a new Tutorial
    router.post("/", checkUser, articles.create);
  
    // Retrieve all Tutorials
    router.get("/", articles.findAll) 

  
    // Retrieve all published Tutorials
    router.get("/published", articles.findAllPublished);
  
    // Retrieve a single Tutorial with id
    router.get("/:id", articles.findOne);
    app.use('/user/stories', router);
  };
```

Comment: When the `user` attribute gets assigned on the `req` object in your app?

Comment: I think you are not assigning the `user` object correctly on the `req`, because the error is straightforward. It is telling you `req.user` is `undefined`, so node.js cannot read `_id` from that `undefined` value.

Comment: sould not be `req.body.user._id`? Can you provide our body?

Comment: I haved updated all the code inside my article controller, can you guys tell me what I'm missing? I'm a newb so i dont really know what i am doing... lol

Comment: @Mu-Majid I never assigned user object on the req. How do I assign it?

Comment: Do you have an authentication system or logic in your app, so you can know the user who is making the request? If no, well, this means that all you routes are public, so assigning the `user` attribute would be as simple as what you've done with `title` for example. Just make the user enter their name when submitting an article, go and fetch that user from mongodb by name and if you found him/her assign the `_id` to `author` attribute and create an article. (this is to give you a basic idea, it is not secure.)

Comment: @Mu-Majid yes, I have included my jwt middleware in the post, can you let me know what I need to do to assign the user object?

Comment: Okay Great, I am sorry, one last question i promise :),  Where do you call the auth middleware? You should call it before calling the `create` (or any other private route), something like this: 

`app.post('/create', auth_middleware, createHandler)`

Comment: @Mu-Majid No problem at all! thank you for being patient and for spending your time to help! I just updated my article.routes above. I called my middleware there!

Comment: When you log the token variable and the decoded variable in the middleware, what are their values ?

Comment: @Mu-Majid the values are username and id

Comment: i mean this var `const token = req.header("authorization");` and this `const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "randomString");`

Comment: @Mu-Majid im not sure what you mean by that... do you have an email i can contact to avoid spamming this post?

Comment: Yeah,  sure. My email is mmajidkamel@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by changing

```
req.user = decoded.user;
```

inside auth middleware, to

```
req.user = decoded;
```

Thank you @Mu-Majid for helping!